# Take (n) characters from a string

Tags: java

I have a string in java, of uncertain length, and I need to take the first 3 and last 3 characters and put them into new strings. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: yes there is, substring() based on string's length

Comment: Have you tried using the method .substring(int begin, int end) ?

Comment: what is the hard way, that you know already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Funny, all solutions are buggy (update: except the one with the regex) and may result in `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when the input string's length is less then 3 (the question explicitly says the length is uncertain). Assuming that str is not null, the proper way would be:

```
String first = str.substring(0, Math.min(str.length(), 3));
String second = str.substring(Math.max(0, str.length() - 3), str.length());
```

Comment: This is neither valid per se. The op asked to get the first three and last three characters of a string. This is impossible for strings with less than three characters. So I think an 'invalid argument' exception would be more in place if the string has less than three characters./

Comment: Depends on the context, he may want to have 2/1 or none. For the former my solution is correct, for the latter, the one using a regex is correct.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the substring method:

```
String text = "Hello world!";
String newText = text.substring(0, 3) + text.substring(text.length-3);
```

This will take "Hello world!" and create a new string which is "Helld!".

If you are looking for a method that you can use:

```
String trimThreeCharacters(text){
    return text.substring(0,3) + text.substring(text.length-3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`str.substring(0, 3) + str.substring(str.length - 3)`

EDIT:

This code is not safe. I leave it for you to check whether string is not too short.
You can also use regular expressions:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.{3}).*(.{3})$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    String s1 = m.group(1);
    String s2 = m.group(2);
}
```

Comment: if str.length is less then 3, then there won't be a match

Answer (score 1):

```
new_string = old_string.substring(0,3) + 
old_string.substring(old_string.lenght() - 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

```
public class Substring {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String input = "very long string, with random content";
                System.out.println(input.substring(0, 3));

                int length = input.length();
                System.out.println(input.substring(length - 3));
        }
}
```

**Result**

```
ver
ent
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this

```
public class MyString
{
    private String value;

    public MyString(String p_value)
    {
        value = p_value;
    }

    public String getFirstThree()
    {
        return value.substring(0, 3);   
    }

    public String getLastThree()
    {
        return value.substring(value.length() - 3);
    }

    public String getNewString()
    {
        return getFirstThree() + getLastThree(); 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyString example = new MyString("hello world");
        String newString = example.getNewString();
            System.out.println(newString);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As milan already said, substring is the way to go here. You can see some examples of use [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/substring.html).

```
String FullName = "Cande Nauer";
String FirstNameChars = "";
FirstNameChars = FullName.substring( 0, 3 );
```

In this example, FirstNameChars will be "Can". To get the last three characters you will have to obtain the length og the string first.

Comment: Your length should be `3` rather than `2`